# Windows Identity Foundation: How to validate a token for signature and expiry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, wif

I'm going through this tutorial to build claims-aware MVC web app using WIF. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx

Sadly the tutorial doesn't mention anything about how to actually validate the token obtained. I tried to search online but couldn't find anything.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my tutorial here

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html

The code you should pay attention to is straightforward

```
       var securityToken = fam.GetSecurityToken( request );

        var config = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration
        {
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
            IssuerNameRegistry   = new CustomIssuerNameRegistry()
        };
        config.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;

        var tokenHandler = new SamlSecurityTokenHandler
        {
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
            Configuration        = config
        };

        // validate the token and get the ClaimsIdentity out of it
        var identity  = tokenHandler.ValidateToken( securityToken );

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal( identity );
```

For this to work you also need a custom issuer name registry that recognizes or rejects the cert the token is signed with

```
public override string GetIssuerName( SecurityToken securityToken )
{
    X509SecurityToken x509Token = securityToken as X509SecurityToken;

    if ( accept the cert ? )
       return x509Token.Certificate.Subject;
    else
       return string.Empty; // rejects it
}
```